# Redefining a method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to redefine the behavior of a function within a library if certain conditions are met, but  execute the original function otherwise. Example:

```
class LibraryToExtend
  def FunctionToExtend(argument)
    if argument == something
      do_something_new
    else
      do_what_the_function_did_originally
    end
  end
end
```

I don't think `super` would work in this instance because I'm overriding the function, not extending it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4470108/#4471202).

Comment: that's no reason to downvote, just close as dup (though I prefer my answer to the 'mile long' answer that question has)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `super` wont work. You need to somehow keep a reference to the old method and you do this by creating an [alias](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/aliasing.htm).

```
class LibraryToExtend
  alias :FunctionToExtend :original_function
  def FunctionToExtend(argument)
    if argument == something
      do_something_new
    else
      original_function()
    end
  end
end
```

As a side note, the convention is that ruby methods are in lowecase and underscores (_) not camelcase (but that's just me being bitchy)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I had not heard about aliases in Ruby before. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, actually I'd like to add that this is a really good question. Added more context